# how to get a value based on a selection in knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using knockout to get some data from an API to fill my textboxes.  I want to get the unit price from the API when you select a drug.  How can I do this?

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Drug:</label>
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <select id="Drug_ddl" data-bind="options: drugs, optionsText: function (item) { return item.Description; }, value: selectedDrug" class="input-xlarge"></select>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Unit Price:</label>
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <input type="number" data-bind="value: unitPrice" step="0.01" class="input-xlarge" id="UnitPrice_txt" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Quantity:</label>
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <input type="number" data-bind="value: quantity" step="1" class="input-xlarge" id="Qty_txt" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Cost:</label>
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: drugcost" readonly="readonly" step="0.01" class="input-xlarge" id="Cost_txt" />
        <input type="button" id="AddDrugs_btn" data-bind="click: addDrug" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add" />

    </div>
</div>
```

This is the code for the viewModel:

```
var claimEntryViewModel = function () {

    var drugs = ko.observableArray([]);
var unitPrice = ko.observable('0.00');
    var quantity = ko.observable('1');
    var drugcost = ko.computed(function () {
        return quantity() * unitPrice();
    });

 var loadDrugs = function () {
        url = apiServerUrl + "Items/";

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function (data) {

                drugs(data);

            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("Is not answered");
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }

 var selectedDrug = ko.observable();

    var addDrug = function () {

        var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(claimDrugs(), function (item) {
            return selectedDrug().ID === item.Id;
        });

        if (!match) {
            claimDrugs.push({
                Id: selectedDrug().ID,
                Description: selectedDrug().Description,
                unitPrice: selectedDrug().SalesPrice,
                quantity: quantity(),
                drugcost: drugcost(),
            });
        } else {
            errorMessage("Already exists!");
        }
    }

return {
        drugs: drugs, 
        addDrug: addDrug,
        selectedDrug: selectedDrug,
        unitPrice: unitPrice,
        quantity: quantity,
        drugcost: drugcost,
    }

}
```

someone kindly provide me with a code that can do this, i'm fairly new to knockout and don't really know how to go about this. thanks

Comment: well `change` in options right , so use a `subscribe` on value binded observable of drugs dropdown (i.e on selectedDrug). Inside subscribe make a ajax call and fill `untiprice` . possible no issue include `optionsValue` . cheers

Comment: Please post your view model code

Comment: @supercool can you provide me with a sample code? i'm kinda new to knockout and don't know much about the subscribe

Comment: Do refer ko doc's which will be a great help to novice developer in ko . cheers .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

super cool is right, subscribing is a good way to handle this.

```
    selectedDrug.subscribe(function (newValue) {
                neededInfo(getSelectedDrugInfoFromApi(newValue));
            });
```

This will call the getSelectedDrugInfoFromApi() every time the selectedDrug observable value changes, and update the neededInfo observable.
Keep in mind not to update the selectedDrug value inside the subscribe function though, as it will create a loop.

Comment: in this case the getSelectedDrugInfoFromApi() is going to be a function and the neededinfo is my unitPrice. is that right?

Comment: Correct, something in the lines of:
    unitPrice(getUnitPriceByDrug(newValue));
will call getUnitPriceByDrug() where the newValue parameter equals the newly selected value, and assign it to unitPrice